# Универсальный скрипт для конвертирования CSV в XLSX

Tags: python, pandas, excel, csv, table

Пытаюсь написать универсальный скрипт для конвертации CSV в XLSX.

Мои данные в подобном формате:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
id,Имя,Адрес, Комментарий
12,Владимир,Москва, Слесарь
15,Олег,"Москва, улица Долгопрудная, д 9, кв 5","Программист, режиссёр"
14,Марина,"Лобня, Интернациональная","Писатель, клипмейкер, дизайнер"
```

Скрипт написал такой:

```
import pandas as pd
    
df = pd.read_csv("1.csv", sep=',\s*', engine='python', encoding = 'cp1251')

for col in df.columns.values:
    df[col] = df[col].str.strip('"')

df.to_excel("1.xlsx", index=None)
```

Однако на выходе имею:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А должно быть как при использовании инструмента Excel "Данные" - "Текст по столбцам", т.е. вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Просьба помочь с решением, не обязательно на библиотеке Pandas. Нужен универсальный скрипт для конвертации CSV в XLS(X), где значение может быть выделено цитатами (т.к. внутри запятые, а они являются разделителями)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По-моему вы немного перемудрили. Попробуйте так:

```
(pd.read_csv("1.csv", sep=",", encoding="cp1251")
   .to_excel("result.xlsx", index=None))
```

результат:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

содержимое файла `1.csv`:

```
id,Имя,Адрес, Комментарий
12,Владимир,Москва, Слесарь
15,Олег,"Москва, улица Долгопрудная, д 9, кв 5","Программист, режиссёр"
14,Марина,"Лобня, Интернациональная","Писатель, клипмейкер, дизайнер"
```

---

**UPD:** для того чтобы проверить является ли ваш CSV файл корректным CSV откройте его в текстовом редакторе.

Вот **битый** файл приведенный по ссылке в комментарии:

```
id,Имя, Адрес, Комментарий
12,Владимир,Москва, Слесарь
"15,Олег,""Москва, улица Долгопрудная, д 9, кв 5"",""Программист, режиссёр"""
"14,Марина,""Лобня, Интернациональная"",""Писатель, клипмейкер, дизайнер"""
```

**NOTE:** обратите внимание на квотирование.

Comment: Попробовал, результат всё равно не такой как нужно. Ссылка на скриншот: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BO1Zw.png

Comment: @Jeygid, у меня все отлично работает для приведенного в вопросе примера данных. Можете выложить куда-нибудь файл, который позволит воспроизвести проблему?

Comment: Если брать "чистый" файл на основе текста, выгруженного утилитой из базы, то распределяется по столбцам корректно. Спасибо! Насколько я понимаю, при сохранении/создании/редактировании в Excel добавляются какие-то специальные символы из-за которых корректно не распределяется? Файл приложил: https://wdfiles.ru/e1fc5f

Comment: @Jeygid, не знаю чем вы его создали, но создали вы __битый__ CSV файл. Я думаю 99% программ/библиотек для работы с CSV файлами не смогут его корректно прочитать

Comment: создал с помощью Excel (CSV с разделителем запятые). А подскажите пожалуйста как вы определили? И как создавали файл вы?

Comment: я использовал данные из вашего вопроса - скопировал и вставил в __текстовом редакторе__ ;) И если я сохраняю данные из Excel в CSV формате, то квотирование у меня правильное. Похоже у вас исходный CSV файл уже битый

Comment: Да, через NotePad++ прогнал, всё ок. Большое спасибо!

Comment: А можете подсказать ещё напоследок, как вы определили, что приложенный мною файл битый? Я открыл его в текстовом редакторе - там что-то много кавычек. В этом причина?

Comment: @Jeygid, да, строка `"14,Марина,""Лобня, Интернациональная"",""Писатель, клипмейкер, дизайнер"""` - будет прочитана как __единственный__ столбец в CSV файле. Потому, что внешние двойные кавычки указывают, что все что внутри - это значение одной ячейки